# Trigger keydown on mobile (safari iphone)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this script that has a keydown event. It is working on desktop, but when i test on my iphone in safari it does not work. Is there a way to trigger a keydown on the input field i am targeting for mobile in safari?

```
        $('label:contains("Rock the Mall Concert")').closest('div').addClass('rockMall');
    $('div.rockMall label:contains("Student")').parent().next().find('input:eq(0)').keyup(function(){
       if ($(this).val() > 1){
         $(this).parent().find(".regQuant").css('display', 'block').text('Limited to 1 per person');
         $(this).val('1');
         var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
         e.which = 13;
         e.keyCode = 13
         $(this).trigger(e);
      }
    });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try with touchstart event.

Comment: Would that be like: $(this).trigger('touchstart', e);

Comment: I don't think the touch api works for what you want to do.
Would you care elaborating your question? I see you're manually triggering events. In some cases for security reasons you can't just trigger events with JS.


Here's the link to the Documentation for TouchEvent.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TouchEvent

Comment: I set a max for what could be entered into an input field. If the user enters a number greater than 1 say for example, 20 they see a message and the input is automatically changed to 1. If the user were to just select continue at the bottom of the page without hitting enter then the total wouldnt actually update to 1 and they would be able to purchase 20 tickets. So I triggered a keydown event for the return key so the total would update. It works except when I test in Safari on an iphone. They  can still purchase over 1 tickets.

Comment: I made a snippet doing what you want to do.
Check it out and let me know!

Answer (score 0):

I made this snippet using jQuery.
You are adding an event 'keydown' but it's not viable in all browsers and platforms so I used 'change' event and it should work good enough.

If the input changes its value the event will trigger.

```js
$('input').on('change', function() {
 // + operator is to parse the value to an integer.
  var ticket_quantity = +$(this).val();
 
  if (ticket_quantity < 1 || ticket_quantity > 20)
  {
   $(this).val(1);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="number" name="ticket_quantity" placeholder="Tickets much?">
</form>
```